# How to turn on SQL commands help in DataGrip?

Tags: command, datagrip

I'm using the latest version of DataGrip from JetBrains and MySql database (also latest), when I press Ctrl+Q for quick reference about a SQL operator (say BETWEEN), nothing is being shown. If I press the same combination on table name I get the help tooltip.

Is there a way to link external documentation to this command?

this is an example about BETWEEN operator

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do that. Database documentation will appear only for built-in functions in some databases.

Comment: Thank you, most of other built-in functions are supported, by I wanted to see if there is another way to add custom docs.